# Sparkfun Can-Bus Shield example not working

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, spi, can-bus

I recently bought a [Sparkfun Can-Bus Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13262), and tried the SparkFun_CAN_Demo from [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/can-bus-shield-hookup-guide) but the program only prints "CAN-Bus Demo" and then does nothing, even when I have it connected into my vehicle's OBD-II port and the key is turned to ON (I can't run the engine because I am in my garage). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SPI pins are located on different pins in Arduino Mega. You have to wire it correctly with your shield. Some shields uses ICSP (6-pin header) for better compatibility but this one doesn't.

See [Arduino SPI Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) for more details (section: Connections)